# Unityでios向けにビルドする際、Shader周りのエラーが発生してビルドが失敗する。

Tags: ios, c#, unity3d

### 解決したい事

Unityで初めてアプリの作成を行っています。
ビルドの際に特に思い当たる節のないエラーが出ており困っております。

3D環境で2D画面に近いタップゲームの作成をしており、
特に特殊なシェーダーを追加した覚えがなくシェーダー周りにエラーが何故出てしまうかの検討がつきません。

何かモバイルで利用できないシェーダーなどを放り込んでしまっている
可能性があるのでしょうか？
ご存知でしたらご回答よろしくお願い致します。

UnityのコミュニティでMACのOSに起因する場合もあるような事が記載されていたのですが、
原因として考えられるでしょうか？

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2019-2-7-build-ios-crashes-in-shader-compile.757754/

### 実際のエラー文

```
Shader compiler: Compile Legacy Shaders/Diffuse - FORWARD, Vertex Program: Internal error, unrecognized message from the shader compiler process.  Please report a bug including this shader and the editor log.
Shader error in 'Legacy Shaders/Diffuse': Internal error, unrecognized message from the shader compiler process.  Please report a bug including this shader and the editor log.
Shader compiler: Compile Hidden/Internal-PrePassLighting - Pass 1, Vertex Program: Internal error, unrecognized message from the shader compiler process.  Please report a bug including this shader and the editor log.
Shader error in 'Hidden/Internal-PrePassLighting': Internal error, unrecognized message from the shader compiler process.  Please report a bug including this shader and the editor log.
Shader compiler: Compile UI/Default - Default, Vertex Program: Internal error, unrecognized message from the shader compiler process.  Please report a bug including this shader and the editor log.
Shader error in 'UI/Default': Internal error, unrecognized message from the shader compiler process.  Please report a bug including this shader and the editor log.
Error building Player: 3 errors
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

### 開発環境

MAC OS Catalina バージョン10.15.3
Unity　Version　2019.2.5f1

導入アセット
DoTween

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/243201

Comment: 解決済みとのこと